# Serious iOS7 issue with multiple web-apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

We're experiencing a major issue with using multiple web-apps on iOS7.

The issue causes already installed web-apps to be overwritten on the device when you add another web-app app (icon changes, app changes).

Replicate as follows:

Install the following webapps, one at a time (ie go to the URL below, wait for page to load in safari, click 'Add to Home Screen', Add)

```
app.ft.com
forecast.io
m.thn.com
splax.net/m/game11.html
sportpursuit.com
```

At some point, typically 3rd, 4th or 5th app, you'll see that 1 or more of the web-apps you've just installed (via Add to Home Screen) appears to get over-written by one of the other apps. See the attached screenshots - in this example the sequence was as follows:

1. Install FT app (app,ft.com) - all OK
2. Install forecast app (forecast.io) - all OK
3. Insall THN app (m.thn.com) - NOT OK! Forecast has now been overwritten by the FT app. We now have 2 x FT apps, the THN app, but no forecast app.

Sometimes this happens on the 3rd app install, sometimes on a later app. Sometimes 1 app gets over-written, sometimes many. In extreme cases (e.g. when you have 10 apps installed) all of them can get overwritten to be the same app!

Device reboot fixes the issue - all apps revert back to how they should be.

Note - this has been present on device since iOS7 Beta 1 and can be replicated in the simulator.

This is a showstopper for public release of iOS7

Screenshots:

Installed FT app - all ok:

[image]

Installed FT app and Forecast app - all OK

[image: Screen Shot 2.png]

Installed THN app - Forecast app has been over-written by FT app

[image: Screen Shot 3.png]

Reboot the device - all 3 apps back as they should be

[image: Screen Shot 4.png]

Comment: You might want to file a bug at https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/‎

Comment: I've logged this issue on bugreport.apple.com ID - 14905558 but haven't received a response yet.

Comment: @iDev let us know when you hear from them.

Comment: This is not a bug reporting site. Also iOS 7 has been released, so I am not sute what you are asking.

Comment: This is really bad!
 
I just added one of my web apps to the home screen, and two duplicates of a different web app I had installed (not mine) were added too.
 
I can also confirm the multitasking problem when tapping the icon of a web app reported by Scott Hawley

Comment: @BlackFrog This still is not fixed with 7.0.3 update.  Any reports from Apple on when this will be fixed?

Comment: Are you sure you are not using the same provisioning profile for all the apps? Just checking...

Comment: @SharanyaKM i'm not understanding what did you asked

Comment: while deploying into the device from Xcode.. you use provisioning profiles in your build settings right?

Comment: @SharanyaKM yes, then...what..

Comment: check whether thats the same for all the apps.. if its the same for all the apps then apps will overlap.. make sure this is not the reason for overlap

Comment: @SharanyaKM  NO, I just confirmed the problem of messed up icons on Add to Home Screen is STILL solidly repeatable after 7.0.2 update - at least for me on iPhone 5 and iPad 3 - same as described above.